# Protractor button click element not visible

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I using protractor for automating testin. But i have element not visible when i run the code.

```
<a class="button button--primary" href="#" rel="modal:close">Click me</a>

   var search = element(by.css('a'));
        expect(search.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

i try this but i have still element not vissible. I have try it manual in the browser and the hyperlink is always present and clickable. idk why i get this error.

Someone knows the issue ?

Comment: it shouldn't give you `elemnt not visible` as you are testing `isPresent`, can you share the entire error log?

Comment: Failed: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:21:31 -0800'
    System info: host: 'ALEXANDER-MSI', ip: '172.21.213.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'

Comment: IsPresent() will just check if element is in dom .. to check visibility can you do a check with isDisplayed()

Comment: They are right, you would not get this error the code you provided.  You must be looking at the wrong thing, it should give you the line error.